# How to view ASCII color codes in Sublime text?

Tags: python, colors, sublimetext3

I have a module called `termcolor` and I use it to `print` important things to the console.

```py
from termcolor import colored
print(colored("Warning: Coding intensely makes you forget about lunch.", "red"))
```

It works in repl.it, but when I moved to Sublime, I only get these:

`[31mWarning: Coding intensely makes you forget about lunch.[0m`, the  being <0x1b>, no idea why it does not copy well.

All I found was to get ASII syntax on the whole file, but that would be problematic because I am coding in python. Is there a plugin that fixes this? Thanks!

Btw, switching IDE's is a no-go. I use sublime on a Core 2 Duo 2GB Ram build for a reason.

Comment: I mean... all you need is a regular terminal, not an IDE... Sublime is a text editor. Just because you are using sublime doesn't mean you can't use a regular terminal. What OS are you on?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm using WIndows 10. I run my scrips with `CTRL`+`B` (Build)

Comment: Right. Just use a terminal to run your scripts. I'm not a windows user, if I recall correctly, the built-in terminal isn't great. But this: https://cmder.net/ seems to be the popular alternative. But even try it with the built-in one.

Comment: But the reason I like the built-in one is that it's just a shortcut away. Is there some sort of integration?

Comment: No. I'm just giving you an alternative. This is why I made it a comment, not an answer. Someone who knows more about sublimetext might be able to provide exactly what you need.

Comment: @SpaceNerden I've marked this as a duplicate because my answer to that other question is exactly what you need to do. Just use the Windows build system, and adjust the path to your python executable as necessary.